# How to show that the cycle $(2 5) = (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (4 3) (3 2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I generally do not have any problem multiplying cycles, but I've seen on Wikipedia that

$$(2 5) = (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (4 3) (3 2). $$

I started following the path of $2$ on the right:

$$2\to3\to4\to5\to \ ?$$

Where does $5$ go? I should stop here, right? Then $2\to 5$, that is, $(25)$. But what about $(23)(34)$?

Comment: When a cycle does not contain an element, that element stays there.

Comment: $5 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 5.$ This says 2 goes to 5. you aslo need to check where 5 goes!

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\phantom{=} \,\,(23)(34)(45)(43)(32)2 \\ =(23)(34)(45)(43)3 \\ = (23)(34)(45)4 \\ = (23)(34)5 \\ =(23)5 \\ = 5. \end{array} $$ Notice how $(34)5=5$ and $(23)5=5$. *By definition*, $(34)$ swaps $3$ and $4$ and **does nothing to the other numbers**. So, $(34)5=5$, and similarly $(23)5=5$.

Comment: The key point @frank000 is referring to is that, more explicitly, when a cycle does not contain an element, such an element *maps to itself*. That is, suppose a cycle consist of $a,b,c,d$, and  you have a product like $(a\;b\;c)(d)$. How do you compute such a product? Starting off, $d\mapsto ?$; well, clearly, $d$ maps to itself for $(d)$. Where does $d$ map to in $(a\;b\;c)$? **It maps to itself**, and that was, I believe, the point of coldnumber using the two-row form: to make it even more explicit that $5$ is mapping to itself. This fact is more apparent with two-row notation than cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another conjugation problem in disguise:

$(2\ 3)(3\ 4)(4\ 5)(4\ 3)(3\ 2) = (2\ 3)[(3\ 4)(4\ 5)(3\ 4)^{-1}](3\ 2)$

$= (2\ 3)(3\ 5)(2\ 3)^{-1}$ (since $(3\ 4)$ takes $4 \to 3$ and fixes $5$)

$= (2\ 5)$ (since $(2\ 3)$ takes $3 \to 2$ and fixes $5$).

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the product(s) 
$$
(2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (4 3) (3 2)
$$
step by step.

Start with $2$, by writing $(2$, and see how the elements map out:

- $2\mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto 5\mapsto 5\mapsto 5\qquad:\qquad(2\; 5$
- $5\mapsto 5\mapsto 5\mapsto 4\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\qquad:\qquad(2\; 5)(3$
- $3\mapsto 2\mapsto 2\mapsto 2\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\qquad:\qquad(2\; 5)(3)(4$
- $4\mapsto 4\mapsto 3\mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto 4\qquad:\qquad(2\;5)(3)(4)$

The process has terminated and we know $(2\;5)(3)(4)=(2\;5)$. That is, we can see that
$$
(2\;5) = (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (4 3) (3 2).
$$
Did all of those steps make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are cycles in $S_5$, $$(2\ 3) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix}=(2\ 3)(1)(4)(5) \\
(3\ 4) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix}=(3\ 4)(1)(2)(5)$$

Hence, $5\mapsto 5$ in both of those cycles.

However, to conclude that $5 \mapsto 2$ you need to follow it through the cycles as you followed 2, starting from the right to the left.

See my answer here for a detailed explanation of composing cycles: [Shortcut for composing cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370420/shortcut-for-composing-cycles/1370438#1370438)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the right, we see that $2\to3\to4\to5$ and $5\to4\to3\to2$. On the other hand, $3\to2\to3$. Every other number just maps to itself, which you can check for yourself.

Note that if a number is fixed, then we don't write it in the shorthand notation for the permutation. Thus we just have $(2\ 5)$